# How to provide metadata values from server to ui method in shiny

Tags: shiny

I'm very new to shiny and butting against something there must be a pattern for, but have had no luck Googling.

I have a simple shiny file (app.R below) that returns a plot for `n` observations.  In addition to making the plot available to the `ui` method, I'd like to pass it `n` to help it size the plot to my liking

```r
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Bob")
    lastNames <- c("Builder", "Gorillas", "Weave")
    ages <- c(25, 26, 27)
    df <- data.frame(firstNames, lastNames, ages)

    # I want to pass this to `ui`
    numFirstNames <- length(unique(df$firstNames))

    mapping <- aes(x = firstNames, y = ages)
    ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_violin() + coord_flip()
  })
}

getHeightInPx <- function(numFirstNames) {
  paste(100 * numFirstNames, "px", sep="")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  # I want height to be a function of numFirstNames as calculated in the server definition
  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot", height = getHeightInPx(2)))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Since `ui` isn't a function and doesn't have direct access to output (to me it's getting to `distPlot` by framework magic) how can I get to data prepared in `server` to help layout the page?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example. Makes it easier for people who want to help to test out their solutions per your example.

Comment: @Kevin full example provided in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/650 tipped me off that you could use the `height` parameter in `renderPlot`.  So I combined that with some use of `reactive` and `observe` to call a function that returns the plot AND gives me the number of elements to use.

I hardly get `reactive` and `observe`, so while it seems to work I would not be surprised to hear that I am abusing them or that there's an easier way.

```r
library(shiny)

renderDistPlot <- function(input) {
  firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Bob", "Carol")
  lastNames <- c("Builder", "Gorillas", "Weave", "Xmasing")
  ages <- c(25, 26, 27, 23)
  df <- data.frame(firstNames, lastNames, ages)

  # I want to pass this to `ui`
  numFirstNames <- length(unique(df$firstNames))

  mapping <- aes(x = firstNames, y = ages)
  plot <- ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_violin() + coord_flip()
  list(Plot = plot, NumFirstNames = numFirstNames)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  renderDistPloatResult <- reactive(renderDistPlot(input))
  observe(output$distPlot <- renderPlot(renderDistPloatResult()$Plot, height = renderDistPloatResult()$NumFirstNames * 100))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  # I want height to be a function of numFirstNames as calculated in the server definition
  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```